# Cannot deploy a self-contained .NET Core 3.0 application to AWS Lambda

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have followed this guide to deploy a .NET Core 3.0 application to AWS Lambda:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/

My serverless.template and aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json files are carbon copies from this article.

My app is an ASP.NET Core app with a target framework of netcoreapp3.0 using the Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer and Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport packages.

When I run `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless` I get the error:

> NETSDK1031: It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.  Please either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false.

Every example I have seen shows this for the msbuild-parameters:

`"msbuild-parameters": "--self-contained true /p:AssemblyName=bootstrap"`

But obviously, I can try the `dotnet publish --self-contained true` command from the command line and I get the same error (NETSDK1031). How is this supposed to work?

If I change the command and run `dotnet publish --self-contained true -f netcoreapp3.0 -r linux-x64` it publishes successfully on my local.

If I update the msbulid-parameters with the same required parameters and run `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless` I get:

> ... publish: MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through the source code of the Amazon Lambda Dotnet CLI tools here: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/blob/6b3c0eaf04bb62995ca1c5dd71b0db7e564e8b74/src/Amazon.Lambda.Tools/LambdaDotNetCLIWrapper.cs)

I found the following code that builds the dotnet publish command:

```
// If you set the runtime to RUNTIME_HIERARCHY_STARTING_POINT it will trim out the Windows and Mac OS specific dependencies but Razor view precompilation
// will not run. So only do this packaging optimization if there are no Razor views.
if (Directory.GetFiles(fullProjectLocation, "*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length == 0)
{
    arguments.Append($" -r {LambdaConstants.RUNTIME_HIERARCHY_STARTING_POINT}");

    if (msbuildParameters == null ||
        msbuildParameters.IndexOf("--self-contained", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
    {
        arguments.Append(" --self-contained false ");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msbuildParameters) ||
        !msbuildParameters.Contains("PreserveCompilationContext"))
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("... Disabling compilation context to reduce package size. If compilation context is needed pass in the \"/p:PreserveCompilationContext=false\" switch.");
        arguments.Append(" /p:PreserveCompilationContext=false");
    }
}
```

My site did indeed include a CSHTML since it was a full-stack web app. Adding the following parameter to the msbuild parameters fixes the issue: `-r rhel.7.2-x64`

But AWS Lambda is not meant to handle full stack applications and static files won't serve properly, so best bet is to break up the application so that the Asp.Net Core lambda project is just a pure API.

Comment: (Author of this tool here) I'm planning on removing this check on *.cshtml as that is a leftover artifact from the .NET Core 1.0 days when razor pages were compiled at runtime. Now a days with .NET Core razor pages are precompiled when the project is built.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i moved `/p:AssemblyName=bootstrap` to my `.csproj` file. See attached image.
[image]